# Can Dynamic LinearLayout work same as List in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have used ListView to populate the JSON Data.Within the List i have structure like

**ListView**

```
    * TextView
    * TextView
    * ListView
```

I am able to populate the outer `listView` and `textView` but not able to populate the `innerList.So` i used the Linear Layout in the Place of `ListView` .can the `LinearLayout` be used same as work of list?

**Fee class**

```
 private void getUsersListData() {


        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?id=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list_description = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                status = jsonObject.getString("Status");
                                DateofReceiptIssued = jsonObject.getString("DateOfReciept").substring(0, 10);
                                ReceiptNumber = jsonObject.getString("RecieptNo");
                                FeeReceivedDate = jsonObject.getString("recivedDate").substring(0, 10);

                                String Description = jsonObject.getString("Description");
                                JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(Description);

                                //   JSONArray descriptionArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Description");

                                for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);


                                    Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
                                    Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");


                                    student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate, Descriptionlist, Amount));
                                }
                                //student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate, Descriptionlist, Amount));

                            }

                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_list.size());
                            CustomFeeListStudentAdapter customFeeListStudentAdapter = new CustomFeeListStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list);
                            listViewfees.setAdapter(customFeeListStudentAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

**CustomFeeListStudentAdapter**

```
public class CustomFeeListStudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    LinearLayout receipt1, receipt2, receipt3, receipt4;
    LinearLayout receipt1detail, receipt2detail, receipt3detail, receipt4detail;


    Context mContext;

    ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list;
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";

    public CustomFeeListStudentAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.student_list = student_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return student_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fee, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            viewHolder.student_profile_fee_status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_status);
            viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_ReceiptIssuedDate);
            viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_ReceiptIssuedNumber);
            viewHolder.student_profile_FeeReceivedDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_FeeReceiptDate);
            viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);
            viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);

        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.student_profile_fee_status.setText(student_list.get(postion).getStatus());
        viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedDate.setText(student_list.get(postion).getReceiptIssuedDate());
        viewHolder.student_profile_ReceiptIssuedNumber.setText(student_list.get(postion).getReceiptIssuedNumber());
        viewHolder.student_profile_FeeReceivedDate.setText(student_list.get(postion).getFeeReceivedDate());

        viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Amount.setText(student_list.get(postion).getAmount());

        viewHolder.student_profile_Fee_Description.setText(student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription());


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView student_profile_fee_status;
        TextView student_profile_ReceiptIssuedDate;
        TextView student_profile_ReceiptIssuedNumber;
        TextView student_profile_FeeReceivedDate;
        TextView student_profile_Fee_Amount;
        TextView student_profile_Fee_Description;


    }
```

**StudentFeeInformation class**

```
public class StudentFeeInformation implements Serializable {
    public String Status;
    public String ReceiptIssuedDate;
    public String ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    public String FeeReceivedDate;
    public String FeeDescription;
    public String Amount;




    public StudentFeeInformation(String status, String ReceiptissuedDate, String ReceiptissuedNumber, String FeereceivedDate,String feeDescription, String amount) {
        Status = status;
        ReceiptIssuedDate = ReceiptissuedDate;
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = ReceiptissuedNumber;
        FeeReceivedDate = FeereceivedDate;
        FeeDescription = feeDescription;
        Amount = amount;

    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedDate() {
        return ReceiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedDate(String receiptIssuedDate) {
        ReceiptIssuedDate = receiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedNumber() {
        return ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedNumber(String receiptIssuedNumber) {
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = receiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public String getFeeReceivedDate() {
        return FeeReceivedDate;
    }

    public void setFeeReceivedDate(String feeReceivedDate) {
        FeeReceivedDate = feeReceivedDate;
    }


    public String getFeeDescription() {
        return FeeDescription;
    }

    public void setFeeDescription(String feeDescription) {
        FeeDescription = feeDescription;
    }


    public String getAmount() {
        return Amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        Amount = amount;
    }


}
```

**frgament_fee**

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/receipt1_fee"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#A4ACB0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Description"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Amount (Nrs) "
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">


                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>



                <LinearLayout  ** can this linear layout be used as listView **
                    android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_linearlayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_description"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Sports"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_amount"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="1000"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />


                </LinearLayout>
```

I want the output of description on the same list.How can this be achieved with the linearlayout?

Comment: Use recyclerview to achieve that.

Comment: on Inner or on Outer List ??

Comment: What are all the things which repeat, make that as an item of recyclerview. Finally you will have list of those items.

Comment: I have created only one class with single layout,Two adapter having two different layout.Can this be achieved using on;y one parent class on which JSON parsing is to be done